# How is primusrun different from optirun

Tags: nvidia, optimus

Primusrun and optirun are two ways of launching an application on the nVidia GPU of an optimus computer. What's the difference between them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between optirun and primusrun (bumblebee)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323969/what-is-the-difference-between-optirun-and-primusrun-bumblebee)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434045),

> Bumblebee, earlier was using VirtualGL as its core and now switched to Primus technology.
>
> optirun uses VirtualGL and primusrun uses the Primus technology.

So it seems that primusrun is new and optirun in old and may deprecate in future.